Fourier transform of a distribution
Let $S'(\mathbb R^n)$ the space of tempered distributions
(a distribution is tempered  if it is  a continuous linear functional on $S(\mathbb R^n)$
given $F\in S'(\mathbb R^n)$ we can define $\hat F $ in this way
$\langle \hat F, \varphi \rangle =\langle F, \hat \varphi \rangle \forall\varphi \in S(\mathbb R^n) $
prove that $\hat F \in  S'(\mathbb R^n)$
what I have difficulties to prove is continuity because
$\langle \hat F, \varphi_k \rangle=\langle F, \hat \varphi_k \rangle\rightarrow \langle  F, \hat\varphi \rangle=\langle \hat F, \varphi \rangle$ but I don't know how to prove this fact: if $\varphi_k\rightarrow\varphi$ in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ then $\hat\varphi_k\rightarrow \hat\varphi $

This is proved in Folland’s real analysis text for example.

@peek-a-boo can you please indicate me where to find it in the book ?

Proposition 8.2 for the definition of the Frechet topology on Schwartz space. Corollary 8.23 for continuity of the Fourier transform on Schwartz space.

@peek-a-boo I was also reading online that is sufficient to prove  this statement : if $f_n\rightarrow 0 $  in $S$ than $\hat f \rightarrow 0 $ in S . I understood this part of the theorem but why it is sufficient prove it for 0 ? and how can I generalize  to $f_n\rightarrow f$?

We’re dealing with linear stuff… so just define $\phi_n=f_n-f$. If this converges to $0$ then $f_n\to f$. You should also review a lot of chapter 5 of Folland.
